# priority-web-sdk : Is there a login expiration time?

Tags: javascript, erp

Is there a way to know the login session is expired? If so how can I recognize it and reconnect the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is at a ‘Form’ level.
If the form is no longer active the user will get an error message when trying to perform an action on that form.
We also have a Form method to check whether the form is still active – called ‘isAlive’.
You can take care of this in the client. Force the user to navigate to the login page after a certain amount of time.